# JSP form to JDBC using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I'm stuck in some code with JSP forms to JDBC.
I'm relatively new at coding, but after a long search on the internet I still haven't solved a problem.
I need to 'insert into' a table the data people type, in my jsp form.

JSP:

```
<form action="CampaignToJDBC" method="post">
        Enter company name: <input type="text" name="pname" /><br/>
        Enter company email: <input type="email" name="pemail" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</form>
```

Servlet:

```
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        // ____________________________________________

        String pname = request.getParameter("pname");
        String pemail = request.getParameter("pemail");

        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        String Query = "insert into campaigns(pname, pemail) values(?, ?)";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(Query);
        ps.setString(1, pname);
        ps.setString(2, pemail);

        ps.executeUpdate();
```

SQL:

```
DROP TABLE campaigns; 

CREATE TABLE campaigns(
Pname varchar2(32),
Pemail varchar2(32)
);
```

My problem is that it doesn't insert it to the database, and with my newly gained experience I have no clue why. I looked up several examples but they all looked like mine.

- Alexander

FULL SERVLET:

```
@WebServlet(name = "CampaignToJDBC", urlPatterns = {"/CampaignToJDBC"})
public class CampaignToJDBC extends HttpServlet {
public static String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
public static String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@datdb.cphbusiness.dk:1521:dat";
public static String ID = "";
public static String PW = "";
private int id = 0;
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String pname = request.getParameter("pname");
    String pemail = request.getParameter("pemail");

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, ID, PW);
        String Query = "insert into campaigns(Pname, Pemail) values(?, ?)";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(Query);
        ps.setString(1, pname);
        ps.setString(2, pemail);

        ps.executeUpdate();

        id = id + 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CampaignToJDBC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CampaignToJDBC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: That the hell is that line inside the servlet??
And pelase provide full code for your servlet class.

Comment: close the connection. here is good [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-insert-a-record/)

Comment: Do you have try catch block? If so does it throw any exception?

Comment: Check for exceptions

Comment: Alright, I added a full servlet. But I tried checking the exceptions, and I have to admit I don't fully understand them

Comment: I think the problem is because of your ID and PW to connec to to dabase, if you are not using any username and password, let them be empty Strings, "" but not "NULL" which is not the same as NULL but are the String objects.

Comment: I just changed it to null, so it wouldn't show on here. Sorry, should have written that up there :)

Comment: Are you using any username or password to connect to your db? If not, set the String ID = ""; String PW = "";

Comment: Yes it is my schools database, so I'm using my login, I will edit and change the code up there to "", so it's not confusing. Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Please separate your business logic from JSP and Servlet side. Make an individual class for the logic, let's say manager/controller or something. Implement the logic there and try it from console or UnitTest.

If it is working fine, than call that method from your Servlet.
First, try with constant parameters.
See log file, generate log info or use System.out.println(); to see what happening. Search for Exceptions in logs.

Is SELECT query works in Servet? Means connection is good.
Try to getting closer.

Comment: I tried what you said with System.out.println("Driver Succesful");. 

And looked at the log. (As I said I'm quite new at this).
This is what the GlassFish server told me:

`Info:   Driver succesful
Info:   ERROR
Info:   Driver succesful
Info:   ERROR
Info:   Driver succesful
Info:   ERROR`

So it looks like it is the connection that fails ):

Comment: Ok. Please copy the error log (stack trace) into your question. In Glassfish, you can use connection pooling, so you can try database connection in the admin console.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED.

The code was correct, but I forgot to add the driver I needed. So all I did was add the library with the driver and it worked. Sorry, my bad!

Thanks to everyone for the help :)